# Подключение внешних тестеров Test Flight

Tags: ios, юнит-тесты

Сборка лежит в itunesconnect уже несколько дней, прошла модерацию и разрешена к выпуску в ручном режиме. Однако я не могу подключить ее для тестирования внешними тестерами. Для тестирования внутренними - доступна. 
Пробовал добавлять тестеров к сборке и сборку к тестерам, по отдельности и группу целиком - результат один и тот же.
Удалял сборку и загружал новую - без результата. Всякий раз получаю сообщение о невозможности отправки сборки на тестирование. [image: image1][[image: image2]][[image: image3]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYmRq.png)[image: image4][image: image5]

Answer (score 1):

Спустя неделю после загрузки сборки она наконец-то стала доступна для тестирования, о чем пришло уведомление на почту.
Что примечательно? Cборку смог отправить на проверку лишь после того как выложил ее в Appstore. Сейчас все выглядит как на скриншоте Виталия.
Мое мнение по данной ситуации - некорректная работа itunesconnect.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо завершить тестирование всех предыдущих сборок - версии.
И начать тестирование новой версии.
Иногда удобней просто билд менять. Это считается как одна версия.

**UPD:**

Для того чтобы разрешить тестирование сборки для внешних тестировщиков сборку вначале отправляют на проверку Apple. У вас на первом скриншоте **"Готово к отправке"** (желтый). Как только Apple проверит смениться на **"Тестируется"** (зеленый) и можно добавлять внешних.

Вот так должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Виталий, ничего не тестируется в настоящий момент. Для всех тестеров указано что нет доступных сборок. Отправленная сборка - первая и единственная для данной версии. Писал в службу поддержки Apple, но ответа нет. Склоняюсь что все описанное - баг itunes.

Comment: Без отправки на проверку внешние тестеры получили доступ. Сначала тоже iTunes Connect тупил - показывал, что нет доступных сборок. Потом как-то само все разрешилось, пока я не спеша готовил описание приложения, даже до загрузки скриншотов не дошел.

Comment: У меня вопрос - как переименовать внешних тестеров? - пробовал удалять и снова добавлять - имя не фиксируется :(